# Media Center Configuration - TV Setup Issue

Tags: windows-media-center, htpc

When attempting to configure Windows Media Center for the first time, a user of mine is unable to get past this screen.  No timeout becomes visible, the screen literally remains in this state with no visible progress or error messages.

We uninstalled and reinstalled the drivers for the Hauppauge HVR-1950 tuner and did not see any change here.  Is this something anyone else has come across?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much an answer, but I have noticed with my MCE that the Updater will kick in every couple of days or so to download the programming data and it takes like 30-45 minutes for it to complete half the time (which is dumb, is downloading the tv guide for the entire world?). This could very well be the normal course of life for MCE. Also, I left my MCE for like an hour to do its thing when I was setting it up.

As far as it being the tuner, you could download the Hauppauge TV software and test the tuner that way. If it works, then it's not the tuner but MCE being dumb.